# jquery draggable helper not displayed in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, draggable

I have a jQuery draggable connected to a sortable. In Chrome, Edge, Opera, and Brave the behavior is exactly as expected: the helper object is displayed during dragging, the sortable elements are shuffled as necessary, and the element gets dropped in the right place. In Firefox the end result is the same, but the helper object is never displayed.

These are the draggable settings:

```
    let dragOptions =
    {
        connectToSortable: sortElement,
        containment: 'body',
        appendTo: 'body',
        delay: 100,
        zIndex: 2000,
        helper: function( event )
        {
            var html               = $( event.target ).html();
            var attributes         = {};
            attributes[ 'id' ]     = 'dragHelper';
            $( 'body' ).append( makeElement( 'div', html, attributes ) );
            return $( '#dragHelper' )[ 0 ];
        },
        start: function( event, ui ) 
        {
            menu.dragging = true; 
            menu.dragItem = event.target;
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) 
        { 
            menu.dragging = false; 
            menu.dragItem = null;
            $( '#dragHelper' ).remove();
        }
    };
```

I added some console.log statements: I expected the helper() and start() functions to be called when dragging starts. In the other browsers that is what happens. It appears that in Firefox those functions are not called until mouse-up (ie, on drop).

How can I make this work in Firefox?